# Buildfire: sdk info

Tags: sdk, buildfire

BuildFire.
Hi, 
I want to edit the fields on the user profile. Currently is asking for phone number, facebook, twitter... And I want to change this profile information. i.e. I want to ask the golf handicap level and some interests instead the social networks of the users.
Did you know the file on the sdk where I can spot these?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to edit a user's profile information, or are you trying to edit the user profile UI itself?

Comment: Yes sorry, I want to edit the profile information. i.e. I want to ask the golf handicap level and some interests instead the social networks of the users. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [user data](https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/User-Data:-Save-user-data-from-the-widget) to store user specific information. For example:

```
    buildfire.userData.save({handicap:"555-555-5555"}, 'customInfo',"1555644732378-06843910305760801",function(err,data){
    if(err)
        console.error('there was a problem saving your data');
    else
        console.log('your data has saved successfully');
});
```

The third parameter is the user token, which is available when a user is logged in, by calling the [getCurrentUser](https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Auth) function.